# Java 11 + Spring Boot + HATEOAS + JAXBException: Class *** nor any of its super class is known to this context

Tags: java, spring-boot, jaxb, spring-hateoas, java-11

I am trying to implement a simple service and use the HATEOAS resource from spring-boot in order to display a link. When the service run, it throws a WARN message in the console with the following:

javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class com.in28minutes.rest.webservices.restfulwebservices.user.User nor any of its super class is known to this context

I am using JDK 11, which forced me to add the dependency, since I was getting a ClassNotFoundException:
"org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime"

But after adding that dependency the spring Resource HATEOAS class is not able to be marshalled.

```
public class User {
    private Integer id;

    @Size(min=2, message="The name should have at least 2 characters")
    private String name;

    @Past
    private LocalDate birthDate;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(Integer id, String name, LocalDate birthDate) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }
...
}
```

```
@GetMapping("/users/{id}")
public Resource<User> retrieveUser(@PathVariable("id") int theId) {
    User aUserResult = service.findOne(theId);

    if (aUserResult == null) {
        throw new UserNotFoundException("id-" + theId);
    }

    Resource<User> aUserResource = new Resource<User>(aUserResult);

    ControllerLinkBuilder aLinkTo = linkTo(methodOn(this.getClass()).retrieveAllUsers());
    aUserResource.add(aLinkTo.withRel("all-users"));
    return aUserResource;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

strangely, this is related to browser. it should work if you call the endpoint using client like "curl" instead of browser.
workaround which helped for me - add:

```
 , produces="application/json; charset=UTF-8"
```

to `GetMapping()`

more details at:
https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-rest/issues/64